# woocommerce api showing 500 response

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using a plugin named Woocommerce POS from webkul and it uses woocommerce api to interact.

When looking at the console, it shows

POST https://919kicks.com/wp-json/pos/v1/get-products 500

and the page returns:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

In fact, I changed the woocommerce rest api credentials a few days back and that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

The error log showed a Fatal Error.

The plugin was using operands on strings instead of int/float.